# Android Parcelable Understanding - parcelling not working

Tags: android, parcelable, parcel

So I thought I would try out Parcelling in Android today, quickly mocked this up:

```
public class Unit implements Parcelable {
    private String unitName;
    private int view;
    private Double value;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Unit() { }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param unitName
     */
    public Unit(String unitName) {
        this.unitName = unitName;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param unitName
     * @param view
     */
    public Unit(String unitName, int view, Double value) {
        this.unitName = unitName;
        this.view = view;
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * Set the name of the unit of measurement
     * @param name
     */
    public void setUnitName(String name) {
        this.unitName = name;
    }

    /**
     * Set whether the unit of measurement is viewable
     * @param view
     */
    public void setView(int view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of the unit
     * @param value
     */
    public void setValue(Double value) { this.value = value; }

    /**
     * Return the unit name
     * @return unitName
     */
    public String getUnitName() {
        return unitName;
    }

    /**
     * Return whether the unit is viewable
     * @return view
     */
    public int getView() {
        return view;
    }

    /**
     * Return the value of this unit
     * @return value
     */
    public Double getValue() { return value; }

    /**
     * Methods for parcelling here
     */

    /**
     * Constructor for parcelling
     * @param in
     */
    public Unit(Parcel in) {
        //
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeList(new ArrayList<Unit>() {
            //huh?
        });
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public Unit createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Unit(in);
        }

        public Unit[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Unit[size];
        }
    };
}
```

As you will probably note my implementation of the methods that I override from the `Parcelable` interface are incomplete. But Carrying on, this class is just an object that is supposed to be parcelable to another class.

Now here is my main activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendParcel);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ArrayList<Unit> units = getUnits();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UnitListActivity.class);
                i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("units", units);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Return an arraylist of units
     * @return units
     */
    public ArrayList<Unit> getUnits() {
        ArrayList<Unit> units = new ArrayList<Unit>();
        units.add(new Unit("acceleration", 1, 56.45));
        units.add(new Unit("kilograms", 0, 5830.54345));
        units.add(new Unit("metres", 1, 543.54));
        units.add(new Unit("kilometres", 1, 32.43));
        units.add(new Unit("grams", 1, 453.654));
        units.add(new Unit("kilograms", 0, 8.5));
        units.add(new Unit("litres", 1, 344.3));
        units.add(new Unit("millilitres", 0, 4543.879));
        units.add(new Unit("decimeter", 1, 5084903.564567));
        return units;
    }
}
```

Basically there is a button when pressed will create an `Intent` and try to parcel an `ArrayList` with the Object that implements the `Parcelable` interface. The class it is trying to pass it to is a `ListActivity` the code for which is here:

```
public class UnitListActivity extends ListActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        UnitListAdapter mTypeAdapter = new UnitListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), bundle.getParcelableArrayList("units"));
        setListAdapter(mTypeAdapter);
    }
}
```

I made this adapter for the `ListActivity` here:

```
public class UnitListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Unit> {

    private ArrayList<Unit> unitsList;
    private Context context;

    public UnitListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Unit> units) {
        super(c, R.layout.unit_values, units);
        this.context = c;
        this.unitsList = units;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {
        View view = null;
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.unit_values, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.unit_name);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);

        //check box set on check changed listener if I get this far for later

        if(unitsList.get(position).getView() == 1) {
            textView.setText(unitsList.get(position).getUnitName());
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            textView.setText(unitsList.get(position).getUnitName());
        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

Now what I don't understand is why in the `ListActivity` this line:
`UnitListAdapter mTypeAdapter = new UnitListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), bundle.getParcelableArrayList("units"));` complains that instead of getting Unit objects, it is getting `Parcelable` objects, since class `Unit` implements them.

Does this mean that in my adapter I have to change the list to expect Parcelable objects and if, it means it is going to change how I read them??

I also don't understand `writeToParcel`, the documentation says that it will flatten the object, so I thought that since I want to flatten the the list I am going to need the `writeList` method, but what after that? it seems like it is flattening the Unit object not the list.

This also leads me to ask about the constructor:

```
public Unit(Parcel in) {
        //
}
```

I am guessing that I need to do something like this:

`readTypedList()` - I don't understand why I have to do this since I will be creating parcels. So I am not sure how to go about implementing this thing...I would really like insight into how parcelling is working, I didn't find the documentation that helpful and how in this example it would work successfully. Help and advice is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to explicitly tell the Parcelable Creator what type it needs to create, so try changing your code to this:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Unit> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Unit>() {
    public Unit createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Unit(in);
    }

    public Unit[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Unit[size];
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work, UnitListAdapter mTypeAdapter = new UnitListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), bundle.getParcelableArrayList("units")); keeps asking me to cast bundle.getParcelableArrayList to ArrayList<Parcelable> but my Unit class implements it, so I don't know why it is complaining, can't extend an interface so...

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Unit> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Unit>() {
    public Unit createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        Unit u = new Unit();
        u.setUnitName(in.readString());
        //...
        //populate all atributes
        return u;
    }

    public Unit[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Unit[size];
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information on your answer? It's usually good practice to explain a little about the answers you post.